# How to manage decimals in c++

Tags: c++

The issue that i encounter is when i try to separate the integer and fractional part of a real number.

```
long double x,y;
x=121.09;
y=(long)x;
x=x-(long)x;
```

Y becomes 121, x in the debugger appears as 0.08999999 but writing it to console shows 0.09.

Also,

```
double x;
int y;
x=121.09;
y=x;
x=x-y;
```

Gives the same results. Why is that? I would need a clean 0.09 as i want to get that as an integer (0.09 -> 9)

How can i get the fractional part of the number without modf?

Comment: `Why is that?` because 0.09 is not representable by the hardware. At least not as a float or double.

Comment: It's because [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), and the only practical way is to either: A) Use custom fixed-precision math libraries in the first place, or B) Format your floating point value as a string, with the required number of digits after the decimal point, then parse the string yourself. Of course, the end result will be a floating point number, which will still be broken. There is no such thing as "clean 0.09" in computer science.

Comment: If you had `12109` to begin with (using decimal fixed point) it would be easy to get a clean 9 from that.

Comment: I recommend reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot